# multiple widget instances with require.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

We built a widget app with backbone and require.js. It works cool with one app instance on page. Now we have a new requirement. We need to run multiple widget instances on same page. Each of app will have its own configurations.

The following test code is not working as we expected:

```
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){

    require([ "app" ], function(app) {
        var bootstrap = {};
        jQueryPB(function() {

            app.testData = i;
            app.startup();
        });
    });
}
```

I wonder how could I instantiate multiple apps and set different configs to them?

Project structure is similar to:

/main.js

```
require.config({
    ....
});

/*code to create multiple instances*/

      require(["app"], function(app){ 
    var instance = new app(color:"yellow"); 
    var instance2 = new app(color:"red"); 

       instance.render();
       instance2.render();
       /*want to create multiple instances here to same page*/
    })
/*above code is not working, TypeError: app is not a constructor*/
```

/app.js

```
define([ "jQueryPB", "backbone", "underscore", "models/app", "views/app" ], function($jpb,
        Backbone, _, appModel, appView) {

    var appInfo = new appModel();
    var app = new appView({
        model : appInfo
    });

    return app;
});
```

/models/app.js

/views/app.js

/view/bags.js

/view/bag (it references app by var app = require("app") , so that it can access app.color)

/collection/bags

/model/bag

I use r.js to compile all js into one

node r.js -o build.js optimize=none

After main.js is fully downloaded, it would start to initialize different app instances.

=================================================updated code

cool. I tried it with similar way:

main.js

```
require(["app"], function(app){ 
var instance = new app({
        testData : 1
});
   instance.testData = "1"; 
   instance.startup();

})
```

app.js

```
define([ "jQueryPB", "backbone", "underscore", "models/app", "views/app" ], function($jpb,
        Backbone, _, appModel, appView) {

    return function app(color) {
        var appInfo = new appModel();
        var app = new appView({
            model : appInfo
        });
        console.log(">>"+color.testData);
        app.testData = color.testData;
        return app;
    };

});
```

a problem is in bag.js, it needs to access the custom variable in app. I use var app = require("app"); console.log(app.testData);  But the output is undefined. Is there a different way to access app instance?

In addition, if require("app"), will it cause a problem if there are multiple app instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, `require` being an asynchronous function, does not execute immediately, and when it finally does execute, the value of `i` will have changed. Ultimately, you will end up with all your instances sharing the same value of `i`, as the loop will have completed before the first `require` callback gets executed. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/J26df/).

You can solve this by creating a closure around each iteration of your loop. This way the original value of `i` is retained within the scope of the require callback.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        require(["app"], function (app) {
          // etc  
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: hi Levi, your method works. But I noticed a different issue. The problem now is that, we reference app in other modules by following way: var app = require("app"). As a result, all app object retrieved in other modules are the one created lastly (i = 2). 

What we need is to create app can be used on same page multiple times. Each of apps will be set with different parameters.  For example, there are multiple tabs on page, each of tabs will have its own app with its own custom data.

thoughts? 

thanks, Ian

Comment: It sounds like your app module is returning an object literal. You want to be returning a constructor, which you can then instantiate upon requiring it, passing it the necessary params. Something like `require(["app"], function(app){ var instance = new app(myParams); })` This way, the individual instances will not share state.

Comment: Please create a new question for your further question(s), as its outside the scope of the current question.

Comment: thanks levi, I opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673061/how-to-access-varible-in-app-js-from-view-module